# How to write python code to access input and output from a program written in C?

Tags: python, c, windows, shell, interfacing

There is a program written and compiled in C, with typical data input from a Unix shell; on the other hand, I'm using Windows.

I need to send input to this program from the output of my own code written in Python.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I've read about `pexpect`, but not sure really how to implement it; can anyone explain the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question?

Comment: The way you describe this, it's hard to tell whether this is a filter program (like `grep` or `sort`) that just takes a stdin stream and writes a stdout stream, or whether it's an interactive CLI program with prompts and responses (like `python` itself). If it's the former, `subprocess.communicate` is all you need; if the latter, `pexpect` is a good option, but nobody can really help you unless you ask a more specific question than "how to implement it".

Comment: so the program in C would be a "module" in python.  I want to access the functions by sending in input from python, obtaining the output of the C program, and using it in my own python code. does that make sense?

Answer (score 6):

i recommend you use the python [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

it is the replacement of the `os.popen()` function call, and it allows to execute a program while interacting with its standard input/output/error streams through pipes.

example use:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("test.exe", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
input,output = process.stdin,process.stdout

input.write("hello world !")
print(output.read().decode('latin1'))

input.close()
output.close()
status = process.wait()
```

Comment: If output is bounded it should be written as `output = process.communicate("hello world !")[0]` as @abarnert said. Read the warnings about the direct usage of .stdin, .stdout [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). In some cases you also need `stderr=PIPE`. `latin1` character encoding is not the best choice. It accepts any input so it hides errors.

Comment: also, sometimes you may need `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to deal with responding to interactive questions and prompts, don't bother with `pexpect`, just use `subprocess.communicate`, as suggested by Adrien Plisson.

However, if you *do* need `pexpect`, the best way to get started is to look through the [examples](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect#Examples) on its home page, then start reading the documentation once you've got a handle on what exactly you need to do.